# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dispersion_plot' NLTK

Tags: attributes, matplotlib, nltk

I am trying to create a dispersion_plot using NLTK. As far as I can tell, I am following the directions. When I run their example calling the example text that comes with NLTK it works. When I call my own text file, it has the above error.

mine:

```
>>> text11 = "Text_test.txt"
>>> text11.dispersion_plot(["semiosis", "dialectic", "essentially", "icon", "logo"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dispersion_plot'
```

Their example code:

```
text4.dispersion_plot(["citizens", "democracy", "freedom", "duties", "America"])
```

Thankful for any advice/help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you have to make it into an NLTK Text object after tokenizing it. Also, your `text11` variable as used in your code is the string `"Text_test.txt"`, not the text inside the file called `Text_test.txt`.

Assuming that

1. you have `matplotlib` and `numpy` installed, which are necessary for `dispersion_plot` to work
2. your file is at `/home/myfile.txt`
3. your file is simple text like [the ones they use](https://code.google.com/p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk/data/corpora/gutenberg/?r=6478)

then this should do it

```
# from Ch. 3
f=open('/home/myfile.txt','rU')    # open the file
raw = f.read()                     # read the text
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)   # tokenize it
mytext = nltk.Text(tokens)         # turn text into a NLTK Text object

# from Ch. 1
mytext.dispersion_plot(["semiosis", "dialectic", "essentially", "icon", "logo"])
```